# Which software is used to do sculpt modeling? (Checkout the image in body)

Tags: 3d, designers, modeling

[image]

Which software is used to create this type of 3d design? How this type of design is created?

Comment: There's no way to tell which software was used. Sorry.  It doesn't even have to be 3D software. It could be a simple photo manipulation in software such as Photoshop or GIMP.

Comment: Yeah. And it could be just a raster painting/art too. If you really need it in 3D, I think you can do this in Blender, but you'll need expert knowledge about how to use various advanced tools in it. I'm too afraid to do this in Blender or any 3D program :P

Comment: See [example here](https://imgur.com/st1ojmM) which was made in Adobe Photohsop. This isn't 3D, just a photo edit of a real statue.

Comment: This could be done in almost any 3d program. To create something like that you'll have to be quite proficient in that 3d program (I'd say 3-6-12-24 months of training depending on your speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. It is a sculpture, painted.

Option 2. It is a sculpture, digitally painted.

Option 3. It is a digital sculpture with a painted texture.

Option 4. It is a digital sculpture painted after the render.

For options 3 and 4, Please, make a simple search: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=software+to+sculpt+3d